# How to filter out duplicate values from CloudWatch logs?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have my Android app's logs in CloudWatch. One event am tracking is giving data like this.

Using 'count_distinct' it's giving count as 242 and while using 'count', it gives 243. So one duplicate entry is there.

I have id field as well. And i guess it might be repeating. How can i filter it out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you have 242 unique IDs among the 243 log events, you can group on ID and filter out the unique results like this:

stats count() as cnt by ID
| filter cnt > 1

Comment: Thanks so much.

Comment: @gangreeen do you know how to filter out duplicate values, of any kind?

Like lets say I want to filter all contactId events logged AFTER the first one.

Answer (score 0):

We can Use the new dedupe field
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html